# Iterate record without Loop in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm literally new in SQL Server and need your help for my query problem.

I have a table like :

```
CurentID    NodeName      PredecessorID
---------------------------------------
AB          predecessor   Start
CD          predecessor   AB
EF          predecessor   CD
OP          predecessor   EF
GH          predecessor   CD
KL          predecessor   GH
IJ          predecessor   GH
LM          predecessor   IJ
MN          predecessor   LM
QN          predecessor   OP
QN          predecessor   KL
```

I need to find all predecessor ID for given `CurentID`.

For example : predecessorID for CurrentID **LM** needs to return:

```
CurrentID  Result
-----------------
 IJ         1
 GH         1
 CD         1
 AB         1
 Start      1
```

and predecessorID for currentID **QN** would return:

```
CurrentID    Result
--------------------
KL           1
GH           1
CD           1
AB           1
Start        1
OP           2
EF           2
CD           2
AB           2
Start        2
```

I can achieve that query using `While Exists (...)`, but it takes a long time to execute for lost data

Does anyone have any tips on how to achieve this result without using a loop?

Comment: Getting two columns like that is possible but is much, MUCH harder than producing the output in rows. Plus, it seems like this is really a job for application code, not database code. Why does it need to be done in the database?

Comment: its not two column..i just showing the result will give two result i will edit my question

Comment: This looks like a job for a recursive CTE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;WITH temp(CurrentID,NodeName,PredecessorID)  
AS  
(  
SELECT  'AB','Predecessor','start' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'CD','Predecessor','AB' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'EF','Predecessor','CD' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'OP','Predecessor','EF' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'GH','Predecessor','CD' UNION ALL  
SELECT 'KL','Predecessor','GH' UNION ALL   
SELECT 'IJ','Predecessor','GH' UNION ALL
SELECT 'LM','Predecessor','IJ' UNION ALL
SELECT 'MN','Predecessor','LM' UNION ALL
SELECT 'QN','Predecessor','OP' UNION ALL
SELECT 'QN','Predecessor','KL'  
)  
, CTE_Recrusive  
AS  
(  
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER By CurrentID) ROWS, CurrentID,NodeName,PredecessorID  
FROm TEMP  
WHERE CurrentID='QN'  --and row=1
UNION ALL  
SELECT c.rows, t.CurrentID,t.NodeName,t.PredecessorID  
FROm CTE_Recrusive c  
INNER JOIN TEMP t on c.PredecessorID = t.CurrentID  
)  
select PredecessorID as CurrentID,rows as Result from  CTE_Recrusive 
order by rows
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation would be nice